# ValueError Please advise

Tags: python, kivy

Error I am getting: I cannot figure out what is wrong with the code

ValueError: CustomView.text1 accept only str

I am calling a method that retrieves bookname, book langauge and book author from database and displays it as a list.

My Python file where I have placed below code

```
from kivy.app import App
import mysql.connector

class ExampleViewer(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        items_1 = {'name', 'lang', 'auth'}

        super(ExampleViewer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        l = self.load_books()
        print(l)
        for i in l:
            d = {'text1': {'text': i[0]}, 'text2': {'text': i[1]}}
            self.data.append(d)
    


        
class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ExampleViewer()
```

My Kivy file

```
<CustomView@BoxLayout>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    text1: ""
    text2: ""
    text3: ""
    Label:
        id: test_label1
        size_hint: 1, None
        on_size: root.height = self.height
        text_size: root.width, None
        size: self.texture_size
        text: root.text1
    Label:
        id: test_label2
        size_hint: 1, None
        on_size: root.height = self.height
        text_size: root.width, None
        size: self.texture_size
        text: root.text2
    Label:
        id: test_label3
        size_hint: 1, None
        on_size: root.height = self.height
        text_size: root.width, None
        size: self.texture_size
        text: root.text3


<ExampleViewer>:
    viewclass: 'CustomView'  .
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 40
    padding:10, 10
    space_x: self.size[0]/3

    RecycleBoxLayout:
        color:(0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8)
        default_size: None, dp(56)

        default_size_hint: 0.4, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Comment: Please format the question. Make sure the code blocks are correct.

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3890632)

Comment: @khelwood thank you, I have edited the code with the help of your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that youu are missing text1 and text2 types, try this :

```
from kivy.app import App
import mysql.connector

class ExampleViewer(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        items_1 = {'name', 'lang', 'auth'}

        super(ExampleViewer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        l = self.load_books()
        print(l)
        for i in l:
            d = {'text1': i[0], 'text2': i[1], 'text3': i[2]}  # this dict is updated
            self.data.append(d)
    


        
class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ExampleViewer()
```